# Button not submitting after switching containers

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, button

I'm trying to make a simple container switch for my login/signup forms which can be used interchangeably. When you click on a 'switch button', it will change containers like so:
[register container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yAe5.png) [login container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGOFU.png)

The problem is that the signup button does not submit anything after switching containers. It is odd because when in its own respective file, it works perfectly but after switching, it does not. The login button works both before and after switching too.

I tried debugging with putting `onClick="alert('works fine?')"` within the button's tag and it showed the alert with no problem.

So what is the problem then? I suspect `show()` and `hide()` are at fault, but it could just as easily be something else.

I know that sharing big amounts of code for queries is bad but in this instance, it could be anything really. I've uploaded the code into a [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/VenkSociety/f3fd44a52f3b0d2f93fcf017aca591ab) here to prevent spam.

Comment: In this case, my friend is best to do the debugging in parts: when you click the #signupFunCode button the registration function is called right? The first question is: is the function being executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 elements with non-unique id `#pd` and 2 elements with non-unique id `#un`, on clicking sign up, the values are retrieved from the first elements with these ids. You have to use different ids for each container.